# Adding list of the same blog posts to multiple pages in Composite C1 (Orckestra CMS)

Tags: c1-cms, orckestra-cms

I've added a blog post to my Orckestra CMS site - fine.

However, when I try and add the blog control to another page - it doesn't work.

```
        <f:function name="Composite.Community.Blog.BlogRenderer" xmlns:f="http://www.composite.net/ns/function/1.0">
            <f:param name="BlogEntriesCount" value="6" />
            <f:param name="BlogListOptions" value="Show image" />
            <f:param name="BlogItemOptions" value="Show title,Show image,Show content" />
        </f:function>
```

If I add another blog page it creates a new blog.

I have added 'Blog' as an application to the new page. It doesn't work. I have duplicated the original blog page - again the blog wont show.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the IsGlobal (labeled 'Show posts from all blogs') to true when implementing the BlogRenderer function?

If this doesn't work, you can try modifying the BlogRenderer function itself by replacing the
`var entries = BlogFacade.GetEntries(IsGlobal);`
with something like
`var entries = "Data.Get<Entries>()`
This should give you all blog entries on the site, which you can filter with lambda expressions as you see fit.

I hope this helps.